# Possible to set the x values used in OpenPyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the following in openypxl. 
I want to use the delay times as the values for the xaxis. I can get the proper series added into the chart fine, but am having issues with the delay. The graph is representing my desired output. Is this possible?

```
chart_object= charts.LineChart()
x_axis= charts.Reference(overall_stats_sheet, (11,2), (11, 5))
chart_object.set_categories(x_axis)
```

Continuing this discussion here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/PGL9-9K-Xok

Comment: What does your code look like so far. This looks pretty straightforward. Series for A5:D5, A9:D9, A10:D10 with B1:D4 for the axis, right?

Comment: Correct, how is the axis set?

Comment: The x-axis is also sometimes referred to as the "category axis", though this really only makes sense for bar charts. Unfortunately, it involves a hard dependency between each data point in a series and the relevant point on the axis.

This in openpyxl 2.3 `chart.set_categories(cats)` is used to set this. `cats` being a reference to the cells that will make up the axis (B1:D1 in your case).

Comment: @CharlieClark I've updated my question with attempted code to match your response. I'm getting errors. Can you guide me to the right direction?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing 2.2 and 2.3 syntax - they're mutually exclusive because 2.3 is a complete rewrite. It's going to be easier to continue this discussion on the mailing list with code and files.

Comment: Ok. Where is that so we can continue? I'm stressing out over this flaw in my code.

Comment: It's linked to from the docs.

Comment: great, I've added a discussion on the openpyxl users group.